# Multiple server blocks in nginx pointing to only 1 block

Tags: nginx, config

I have tried to setup nginx on my server but I am unable to create multiple server blocks.

I have created two files : xxx.com and yyy.com in the sites-available folder and symlinked it in the sites-enabled folder. But both domains point to only 1 site. Like opening xxx.com opens yyy.com

For site xxx.com and yyy.com (replace xxx.com with yyy.com), I have following config file in sites-available :

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name xxx.com www.xxx.com;
    root /var/www/xxx.com/public_html;
    index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }
}
```

for default :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    #listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    #listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    #include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    #include snippets/ssl-params.conf;


    #root /var/www/public_html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;
    #location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    #       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php7.0-fpm:
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }
}
```

I have also added entries for thre respective domain in the /etc/hosts and also set nginx.conf `server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;`.

What could I be missing?

Comment: Test the configuration using `nginx -T`. If you remove `xxx.com`'s configuration, does `yyy.com` appear?

Comment: What does your nginx.conf look like? Did you reload / restart after adding the second config file?

Comment: @RichardSmith : Yes, if I remove xxx.com shows yyy.com

Comment: @ShawnC. : Yes, I reload nginx everytime I make changes.

Comment: What does your nginx.conf look like?

Comment: nginx.conf     https://justpaste.it/1hy6z